# Using `mv` to rename a file in nested directory

Tags: mv

Suppose I want to rename a file several directories down. I do,

```
mv dirA/dirB/dirC/name.suf dirA/dirB/dirC/newname.suf
```

Is there any easier way to type this? One option would be

```
cd dirA/dirB/dirC
mv name.suf newname.suf
cd -
```

Anything better?

Comment: Both of these seem to work and achieve what you need. Option 2 is a bit safer - making sure you do not miss any directory and move the file elsewhere. You can create a shell script that will perform all 3 operations in one line - but how often would you really need it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your shell, you could make use of the filename expansion features. In ZSH (and, I believe Bash, too), you could run

```
mv dirA/dirB/dirC/{name,newname}.suf
```

which expands to

```
mv dirA/dirB/dirC/name.suf dirA/dirB/dirC/newname.suf
```

bevore executing the `mv` command (see zshexpn(1)).

Comment: Wow, really cool. Thanks! Why does my bash have a man entry for zshexpn(1)? Seems weird.

Comment: Propably because ZSH is installed on your system (Debian: `dpkg-query -l 'zsh*'`)